# Kill a thread after a certain amount of time in C

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

Kill a child thread from the parent.

I'm modelling a customer as a thread in C. Now the customer has a property which specifies how long it can wait before it gets serviced.
If the time limit exceeds the wait time , than customer will go back from the service provider.

I know about pthread_cancel(), but how will I keep track of time for a thread.

How can I solve this problem with the thread printing if it was serviced or not before exiting.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to kill it from the parent. You can use a conditional variable in the child thread routine which gets set only if parent has time for it. Use pthread_cond_timed_wait and exit after timeout if the conditional variable is not set.

Comment: Sounds like you want to model customers who give up and leave the queue if they are not serviced within a reasonable amount of time. Very different from a shop keeper who kicks customers out if they've been waiting too long. Why not have the customer thread wait by calling `pthread_cond_timedwait(...)`?

Comment: P.S., Killing a thread within a process almost always is a Bad Idea. It's very difficult to guarantee that any data that it shared with other threads will be in a safe and reasonable state after the kill. Threads always should _cooperate_ with each other. If thread A wants thread B to die, then it should _ask_ thread B to cleanly shut itself down.